# jQuery Mobile Internal Pages Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am using the internal pages feature within jQuery Mobile that works fine, but only in specific cases. Most of the links within the application use the "standard" loading features of jQuery (where the desired page is loaded via AJAX, and the first container with `data-role="page"` is placed in the DOM).

However, there are several pages that contain multiple containers with a `data-role="page"`, which are intended to used as internal pages. In other words, the first `page` container in the HTML document contains links which will internally link to the other pages within the DOM.

Using the "standard" loading method described above, the internal links do not work. However, reloading the page so that the entire DOM is loaded solves this issue.

I know I could link to this page by adding a `rel="external"` attribute the link, but doing it that way removes all of the nice transitions that jQuery Mobile provides via the "standard" method of loading.

How can I solve this issue without adding a `rel="external"` attribute?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found this solution to be the most efficient manner for handling my situation. It does not require the use of classes on anchor tags to indicate whether or not the link will include separate pages. This code will simply look for additional pages, all within a single HTTP request.

Jasper got my wheels spinning in the right direction.

```
(function($) {
/**
 * This code will load all of the internal pages within the DOM of an HTML element
 * and transition the first one into place, just as the "standard" way of loading
 * a page, but it includes all internal pages
*/

  $(document).bind('pageload', function(event, ui) {
  //Find all of the pages and dialogs in the DOM
    var response = ui.xhr.responseText;
    var data = $(response).filter('section[data-role="page"], section[data-role="dialog"]');

  //Make sure that the given psuedo page does not already exist before adding it
  //Skip the first matched element, since jQM automatically inserted it for us
    for (var i = 1; i <= data.length - 1; i++) {
      var current = data.eq(i);

      if (current.attr('id') && !document.getElementById(current.attr('id'))) {
        current.appendTo('body');
      }
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Your `document.pageload` event handler is going to be bound every time a page is initialized. You've got the `if/then` statement so you aren't adding pseudo-pages multiple times but you're still running the `document.pageload` event once for every pseudo-page initialized. So by the fourth page the `document.pageload` event handler will be running 4 times rather than once. Basically you can just remove the outer delegated event handler as your `document.pageload` is almost the same thing. Good stuff though, clean it up a bit and I'll certainly up-vote.

Comment: @Jasper lol Didn't even think of that. Thank you for catching that.

Comment: When I run this code data always has a count of 0. I have several divs with `data-role="page"` in the attributes. Any ideas?

Comment: I had to replace it with `$(response).find('div[data-role="page"], div[data-role="dialog"]');`

Answer (score 1):

jQuery Mobile by default only loads the first `data-role="page"` or the first `data-role="dialog"` element from an external document. The `<head>` section is even omitted.

A fix would be to either put all pages into a single HTML document or place each pseudo-page in it's own HTML document.

You could write some code that manually grabbed all of the pseudo-pages in an external document:

HTML --

```
<a class="multi-page-link" href="some-external-document.html"></a>
```

JS --

```
//when a pseudo-page initializes this code will run
$(document).delegate('.ui-page', 'pageinit', function () {

    //find elements tagged with the above class and bind to their `click` events
    $(this).find('.multi-page-link').bind('click', function () {

        //show the loading spinner
        $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();

        //create AJAX request for href of link
        $.ajax({
            url      : this.href,
            dataType : 'html',
            success  : function (response) {

                //on successful response, find all the pseudo-page elements in the external document and append them to the `<BODY>`
                var $pseudoPages = $(response).filter('[data-role="page"], [data-role="dialog"]').appendTo('body');

                //now hide the loading spinner
                $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();

                //and navigate to the first pseudo-page that was just added to the DOM
                $.mobile.changePage($pseudoPages.eq(0));
            },
            error    : function (a, b, c) { /*Don't for get to handle errors*/ }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

I think there is a plugin for this but I don't know where it is or if it's being supported.

Comment: Ahh.... Great idea! Let me try this out and I'll let you know my outcome. Just out of curiosity. If the user visits the page several times in one session. This looks like it will continue to add the internal pages to the DOM, even if those pages already exist and have the same ID. I should probably check for this as I add the pages to the DOM, shouldn't I?

Comment: I actually just found this on the jQM docs page: https://github.com/ToddThomson/jQuery-Mobile-Subpage-Widget

Comment: @spryno724 Yeah you would want to check if the pseudo-pages are already in the DOM. That's easy, you can select by ID and if something comes-up, just replace it with the new one or leave the old one in place.

Comment: With a few minor changes (see the edit I suggested), it works great! My only problem now is that I cannot use the back button to return to the previous page, because the URL is not updated. :( Any suggestions?

Comment: @spryno724 I haven't played with the `pushState` plugin that is included in jQuery Mobile, but it will allow you to update the URL as you change the page, re-enabling the back button.

Comment: @spryno724 `event.preventDefault()`/`event.stopPropagation()` aren't necessary because `return false;` does both. You just have to make sure to put `return false` at the end of the function because it ends the execution of the function. This means that if an error occurs before the end of the event handler, `return false` won't be read and the default behavior will happen, but this is only a problem during debugging. Also `$(this).attr('href')` will return a relative URL and `this.href` will return a full URL, but both point to the same place and `this.href` is quicker.

Comment: Thank you for your help! From your example, I was able to come up with a solution that also solves the issue mentioned in the comments. See my answer for the code I am using.