# jQuery Mobile AJAX navigation to a page having a dialog

Tags: jquery-mobile

JQM AJAX navigation doesn't work well when navigating to a page with an in-page dialog?

page1.aspx:

```
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">Page 1</div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <a href='page2.aspx'>Click here</a>
  </div>
</div>​
```

page2.aspx:

```
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">Page 2</div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <a href='#popup' data-rel="dialog">Popup</a>
  </div>
</div>​

<div data-role="dialog" id='popup'> <!-- This is not loaded on AJAX navigation -->
  <div data-role="header">Page 2 Popup</div>
  <div data-role="content">
    Popup content
  </div>
</div>​
```

When you click the link from Page 1, it doesn't load the `<div data-role='dialog'>` of Page 2.

How do you get around this issue?

Comment: JQM loads first `data-role=page` in file.asp and neglects everything else. Each page/dialog should be in a separate file. Dialogs are treated as pages. Use a popup instead.

Comment: I tried `data-role=popup`. It makes no difference, it is not loaded either. Is there a way to have a popup in the second page?

Comment: Popup should be within page div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [workaround here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853886/jquery-mobile-internal-pages-issue). I modified it a little:

```
$(document).bind('pagecontainerload', function (event, ui) {
  // Find all dialogs in the DOM
  var response = ui.xhr.responseText;
  var data = $(response).find("div[data-role='dialog'],div[data-role='popup']");

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var node = data.eq(i);

    if (node.attr('id') && document.getElementById(node.attr('id')))
      $('#' + node.attr('id')).remove(); // Delete existing one

    node.addClass('cache').appendTo('#form1'); // or appendTo('body')
  }
});
```

I added the class `cache` for cleanup purpose.